# Why does LastName not show in C# string concat operator below

Tags: c#

I've got code like the following where adding the ?? operator causes **last**  to disappear.

*Expected Result:*  was that if **first**  was null then **first** would be replaced by "" and that "" would be concatinated with **last** giving just **last** as the result.

*Actual Result:* What happened was the result I got was just **first**.

```
var first = "Joe";
var last = "Smith"
var str1 = first + last; // gives "JoeSmith"
var str2 = first ?? "" + last // gives "Joe"
```

Comment: I don't understand why you expected that only the last-name was shown. The [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) returns the left-hand operand if it's not null, only otherwise it needs to evaluate and return the the right hand operand. In your example `"Joe"` is clearly not null.

Comment: Indeed, you might want to clarify that third sentence - did you mean "I thought it would be just last name if `first` was null"?

Comment: Operator precedence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a matter of precedence. `+` binds more tightly than `??`, so your code is effectively:

```
var str2 = first ?? ("" + last)
```

It sounds like you probably meant:

```
var str2 = (first ?? "") + last
```

But there's no point, given that string concatenation with null is equivalent to string concatenation with an empty string - so just use `first + last` as you already have with `str1`.

Comment: Thanks @jon-skeet  Makes sense. I should no better than to code before 7 in the morning.

Comment: @PeterKellner: I find the time of day isn't nearly as important as the caffeine level :)

Comment: I prefer not to edit other people's answers when there's not much to fix. Also, I misread the date and thought this was much older than it is, whoops.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior of the null coalescing operator `??`. It will use the first value, unless it is null in which case it will fall to the second. Consider how this appears with the variables replaced:

```
var str2 = "Joe" ?? "" + "Smith";
```

Since "Joe" isn't null, it will set `str2` to that and ignore the rest of the expression. If you wanted to only coalesce the first name, then you would need to group it with parentheses to replace any null instances of `first` with the empty string:

```
var str2 = (first ?? "") + last;
```

However, this really doesn't make any difference from your existing code, as your null will simply be an empty string and yield the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Since *first* is not `null` it returns "Joe"

Comment: The OP was confused about the precedence though - he's expected that part to *then* be followed by the concatenation.

Comment: Please explain why this was closed as off topic.